# Okular not opening links in web browser

Tags: 18.04, firefox, pdf, okular

When I go to click on hyperlinks in a PDF document from ocular, it opens the resulting page in the text editor, not in Firefox as expected.

Some output to show that Firefox should be default...

```
$ update-alternatives --get-selections|grep www-browser
gnome-www-browser              auto     /usr/bin/firefox
x-www-browser                  auto     /usr/bin/firefox

$ less /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache | grep html
application/xhtml+xml=firefox.desktop;
text/html=firefox.desktop;
```

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, 4.18 kernel, GNOME desktop